# A certain regular expression that should match does not match in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am working with determining if certain regular expressions apply to some specified text, and for this I wrote a short Python script.  I am having trouble with a certain regular expression because I tested it in an app on my iPhone designed to test regular expressions on specified text, and the regular expression matches the text in the app.  But when I try the expression on the text in a Python script, there is no match.  I am pasting below a short Python script that tests the regular expression on the desired text and a photo of the regular expression app that shows that the regular expression does match the text.  What I would like, if possible, is to get an explanation as to why the regular expression does not match the text in Python.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much.

```py
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import regex as re

expression = r'((?<=(^|\n)[\w [[:punct:]]]{1,100})(?<!Chapter[ \t]{1,100}[0-9]{1,100})(?<!\w{2}—[\w [[:punct:]]]{1,100})—(?![a-z]))'

text = r'Section 1—From Strength to Weakness'

replacedText, numMatches = re.subn(r'(' + expression + r')', r'<mark>\1</mark>', text)
print('Number of matches: ' + str(numMatches) + '\n' + replacedText)
```

[image: Photo of RegEx app that shows match]

Comment: A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width in Py.

Comment: @Heo Shouldn’t Python produce an error message to this effect when the script is run?  When I run the script, I get no error message at all.

Comment: @Heo, this is not true for the `regex` module as can be seen in [their docs](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#variable-length-lookbehind)

Comment: To clarify, I do get an error message if I use the standard ‘re’ package.  But I am using the extended ‘regex’ package, imported as ‘re’, and I get no error with that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I would like, if possible, is to get an explanation as to why the regular expression does not match the text in Python

The problem is that the `[[:punct:]]` character class appears inside a character class. You need to stick to the brackets that `[[:punct:]]` already has, and add the other characters inside that notation. In other words, regard that `[[:punct:]]` notation as a character class notation, with `[:punct:]` appearing in it. There should not be *another* pair of brackets.

So write `[\w [:punct:]]` instead of `[\w [[:punct:]]]`, ...etc.

Here is the correction:

```
expression = r'((?<=(^|\n)[\w [:punct:]]{1,100})(?<!Chapter[ \t]{1,100}[0-9]{1,100})(?<!\w{2}—[\w [:punct:]]{1,100})—(?![a-z]))'
```

Comment: Wow! Your explanation is right on point.  With the corrections that you suggest, there is a match in Python and the problem that I was encountering is gone.  Thanks so much for pointing out the problem.